# Python dictionary rename key and group

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, key

I am trying to rename some keys and group the values for the grouped keys. My content looks like this:

```
text_image_old = {10_pdf 10_pdf0: "some text", 10_pdf 10_pdf1: "more text", 10_pdf 10_pdf2: "even more text"}
```

Using regex, I can iteratively replace the names, such that only 10_pdf would be left, but due to the loop, the text would just contain the values "even more text" (e.g. the last value):

```
text_image_new =  {re.sub('[a-zA-Z0-9_]+.pdf[0-9]', '', k): v for k, v in text_image_old.items()}
```

How could i replace the keys and group the values? Thank you!

Edit: the expected output should look like this

```
text_image_new = {10_pdf :"some text" "more text" "even more text"}
```

or if its easier to get:

```
text_image_new = {10_pdf :"some text more text even more text"}
```

Comment: Can you please share your expected output?

Comment: I have edited the question. Thank you for your comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this should work for you, or at least help solving your problem:

```
text_image_old = {'10_pdf 10_pdf0': "some text", '10_pdf 10_pdf1': "more text",\
                  '10_pdf 10_pdf2': "even more text"}

new_dict = {}
for k, v in text_image_old.items():
    k = k.split(' ')[0]
    if k in new_dict:
        new_dict[k] += v + ' '
    else:
        new_dict[k] = v + ' '

print(new_dict)
```

Comment: you can still implement you regex here if necessary, I just use split because from what you provide in question it seems doing the job here